# Functions in promise not called in unit-testing karma

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, angular-promise, function-call

The following test for the following function always succeeds because it never calls any of the "then", "catch" or "finally" functions.

function:

```
getItems: function() {
    return $http.get(serviceRoot+'/getItems/'+idService.id()).then(function(response) {
      return commonService.validateServerJson(response.data.options);
    })
  },
```

The test:

```
it('should get items',function(done) {
    spyOn(commonService, 'validateServerJson').andCallThrough();
    spyOn(idService, 'id').andCallThrough();
    itemsService.getItems().then(function(response) {
        expect(response.value).toEqual("fff");
        expect(commonService.validateServerJson).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(idService.id).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }).catch( function(response) {
        expect(false).toEqual(true);
    }).finally(done);
```

});

Comment: Have you had any luck solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend%20$httpBackend) to make sure that your $http promise gets resolved.

You *may* also need to manually invoke the AngularJS lifecycle to make sure that the promise you're chaining off the $http call resolves.

I'd advise using `done.fail('message')` instead of `expect(false).toEqual(true)` and get a better report of what happened. This also removes the `finally` from the picture, simplifying the test.

Does this work any better?

```
it('should get items', function(done) {
    var mockHttpResponse = { /* INSERT EXPECTED HTTP RESPONSE */};
    $httpBackend.when('GET', 'INSERT/EXPECTED/PATH/HERE').respond(mockHttpResponse);
    spyOn(commonService, 'validateServerJson').andCallThrough();
    spyOn(idService, 'id').andCallThrough();
    itemsService.getItems().then(function(response) {
        expect(response.value).toEqual("fff");
        expect(commonService.validateServerJson).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(idService.id).toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
    }, function(){
        done.fail('getItems() promise was rejected');
    });
    $httpBackend.flush(); //Resolve $http promise
    $rootScope.$digest(); //Force AngularJS lifecycle to run and resolve other promises.
});
```